How to tidy, simplify relationships in a Directed Acyclic Graph (DAG) by adding converging subgraphs?
Example A Image
Example B Image
Both examples aim to illustrate what a converging node (subgraph) is (N * N) and how it visually simplifies the relationships in a DAG. This simplification can potentially be measured by certain objective indicators, such as a decrease in the total in(out)-degree after adding a converging node.
Example A:

input: [[1,2],[1,4],[3,2],[3,4]]
output: [[1,5],[3,5],[5,2],[5,4]]

Example B:

input: [[1,2],[1,4],[1,6],[3,2],[3,4],[3,6],[5,2],[5,4],[5,6]]
output: [[1,7],[3,7],[5,7],[7,2],[7,4],[7,6]]

My expectation is to obtain a procedure from existing algorithms related to it (if there is one) to calculate the converging node and merge it into the DAG without changing any node reachability.

Isn't it just taking nodes that share a destination and adding an intermediary node for them?

Yes, in common case  N * M ( N sources connect to M targets ), it is just converging edges as many as possible at the added intermediary node, and the reachability of each pair of nodes remains unchanged.
